# Sharepoint 2010 - how to communicate with ServiceStack.net services?

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, servicestack, strongname

Is it possible to communicate between SharePoint 2010 and servicestack services using strongly typed clients? ServiceStack client lib is running on .net 4 framework (**it is not correct see my edits section**) ( SP2010 is on .net 3.5) causing BadFormatImage exception...

I tried to connect by WCF wizard (from sharepoint designer) but it was unsuccessful.

**EDIT**
The real problem is in my nant task signing stack libs. I used .net 4 ilasm instead of 2.0.

```
<target name="signss" description="sign service stack assemblies">
    <foreach item="File" property="filename">
        <in>
        <items basedir="lib">
            <include name="**/ServiceStack*.dll" />
        </items>
    </in>
    <do>
        <echo message="${filename}"/> 
        <echo message="${path::get-directory-name(filename)}"/> 
        <exec failonerror="true" program="C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.0A\Bin\ildasm.exe">   
            <arg value="${filename}" />
            <arg value="/out:${path::get-directory-name(filename)}/${path::get-file-name-without-extension(filename)}.il" />
        </exec>


        <exec failonerror="true" program="C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\ilasm.exe">   
            <arg value="${path::get-directory-name(filename)}/${path::get-file-name-without-extension(filename)}.il" />

            <arg value="/dll" />
            <arg value="/key=ss.snk" />
            <arg value="/output=${path::get-directory-name(filename)}/${path::get-file-name-without-extension(filename)}.dll" />
        </exec>
    </do>
    </foreach>
  </target>
```

Nant task now sign and recompiles libraries to .net 2 assemblies but still I have got problem when I try to use ServiceStack.Common in my sharepoint 2010 solution.

```
var client = new JsonServiceClient("http://host:8080/");
```

gives error

Error   16  The type 'ServiceStack.Service.IServiceClientAsync' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'ServiceStack.Interfaces, Version=3.9.60.0, Culture=neutral, **PublicKeyToken**=null'.

I should change public key token in referenced assemblies, now is null ... I will try to edit nant task to correct that key on .il files.

Comment: Have a look at the guidelines and limitations in [ServiceStack's SOAP Support](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/wiki/SOAP-support). Also this example showing [SharePoint together with ServiceStack](http://www.mattjcowan.com/funcoding/2012/05/04/building-a-web-api-in-sharepoint-2010-with-servicestack/) may help.

Comment: Is there any way to get actual, SS assemblies with strong names using nuget? Sharepoint solutions referenced asseblies must have strong names.

Comment: strong named dlls has been requested for v4, [vote on the feature to get it prioritized](http://servicestack.uservoice.com/forums/176786-feature-requests/suggestions/4458755-add-optional-strong-named-nuget-packages)

Answer (score 2):

If you would like to use Service Stack Client with sharepoint 2010 you should:

- Download sources from github (the newest commits using .net 3.5):

ServiceStack https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/4cdc5b5a87ea18dce77840252b72e680e29a6bd5

ServiceStack.Text https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/cd1f130c1a9a2c4c79e62fb3e487197956d1f56b

- Sign assemblies ServiceStack.Common, ServiceStack.Text, ServiceStack.Interfaces